# cshrc not getting sourced after installing miniconda

Tags: macos, csh, miniconda

Hope this is an easy one for somebody:

- After installing miniconda on mac, my ~/.cshrc file no longer gets sourced when running a new shell.
- The system-wide cshrc is getting sourced from /etc/csh.cshrc, but not the one in my home directory.
- If I manually run `source ~/.cshrc`, then everything looks fine.
- My shell is still set to /bin/csh as expected.
- I am pretty sure it is related to the miniconda install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem here:

When miniconda installs, it created a new .tcshrc file, which did not previously exist.

csh must prefer sourcing from .tcshrc, and ignores .cshrc if it is found.

I just had to delete the .tcshrc file that miniconda created and everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning the preference. I had the same issue after installing miniconda.

I did not want to delete .tcshrc as it has info for setting up conda, so I simply added the following line to .tcshrc:

source `~/.cshrc`